# How to vertically center a icon within select2 option?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment, jquery-select2, font-awesome

I have a [select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) with the options formated. I add a fontawesome icon on the right. 
But it's not vertically aligned respect the select option. This image speaks for itself:

[image]

To put it on the right I add `float: left; position: relative;`.

Check thi fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/uAnLJ/10/**

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.fa-check-circle{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
function format(referencia) {
    if (!referencia.id) return referencia.text; // optgroup

    if ($(referencia.element).data('active') == "1") {
        return referencia.text + "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>";
    } else {
        return referencia.text;
    }
}

$("#mysel").select2({
    width: "100%",
    formatResult: format
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="mysel">
    <optgroup label="First group">
        <option value="0" data-active="1">Hello</option>
        <option value="1" data-active="0">Stack</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Second group">
        <option value="2" data-active="1">Overflow</option>
        <option value="3" data-active="1">Friends</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Do you have any idea/alternative to do it?

If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height` here:

```
.fa-check-circle {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uAnLJ/11/)

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding some padding to `.fa-check-circle` like so:

```
padding-top:2px;
```